# Replace data frame columns based on column names

Tags: r

I want to replace the columns of an empty data frame with columns of another data frame containing measurement data based on matching column names. To illustrate the problem, here some example data:

```
#sample data
set.seed (543)
input <- data.frame(replicate(6,sample(0:100,20,rep=TRUE)))
colnames(input) <- c("Time", "C2", "B1", "A1","A2", "A3") #no specific order predictable here

#create empty data frame 
test <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 10, nrow = nrow(input)))
colnames(test) <- c("Time", "A1", "B1", "C1","A2", "B2", "C2","A3", "B3", "C3")
```

I applied the `match` function to do the column name lookup

```
#match column names and generate index vector
matching <- match(colnames(test),colnames(input))
#remove NA from vector
matching <- matching[!is.na(matching)]
```

But when I simply copy the measurements data frame into the empty one using the index vector

```
test[,matching] <- input[,1:ncol(input)]
```

R fills always the empty 'test' data frame from 'left to right' regardless of the order specified in the 'matching' vector. I would like to obtain a 'test' data frame where columns not present in the 'input' data frame are still filled with zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your values for matching, everything goes as it should, you just inverted the parameters for match :)

This will work:

```
matching <- match(colnames(input),colnames(test))
```

Note that you can do much simpler with this:

```
test[,names(input)] <- input
```

Comment: make sure to use `test[, colnames(input)] <- input` when `names` returns `NULL`